# Changing a file name using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Hi I succeed changing a file name using VBS by using this code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set oFldr = fso.getfolder("C:\v\t_TEST\")

for each ofile in oFldr.Files
 if lcase(fso.GetExtensionName(ofile.Name)) = "txt" then
  ofile.name = "index.txt"
  Exit for
 end if
Next
```

Now I would like to make every .txt file placed on folder "v" (subfolders) to change it name also.
Or to define a changing path ("C:\v\t_XXX), so each folder starts with t_ in this path will change inside it all files end with .txt.

How do I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for....

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFldr = fso.getfolder("C:\v\")
For Each fld In ofldr.SubFolders
    If Left(fld.name, 2) = "t_" Then
        Set ofls = fso.GetFolder("C:\v\" & fld.name & "\")
        For Each ofile In ofls.Files
            If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(ofile.Name)) = "txt" Then
                ofile.name = "index.txt"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Please deal with `Set ofls = ofls = fso.GetFolder("C:\v\" & fld.name & "\")` - perhaps by using the `fld` you already have.

Comment: Oops! Thanks ekkehard